# Parse Java String of JSON to keep only relevant fields

Tags: java, json, string, parsing

So, at a point in my Java app, I make a call to an API and it returns data **as a string** in this format:

`String1` =

```
{
   "data":{
        "metadata":{
             // something
        }
        "node":{
              "edges":[
                   {//edge 1},
                   {//edge 2},
                   ...
              ]
        }
   }
}
```

Now due to paginated data, I have to make the API call multiple times. Therefore, I have `String1`, `String2`, ..., `StringN`.

Now I want to generate a `StringComposite` that should leave out the other fields and combine all the `edges` json objects to a list, and look like this:

```
{
   "edges":[
      {//edge 1},
      {//edge 2},
      {//edge 3},
      {//edge 4},
      ...   
   ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's a `StringComposite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

- Create a POJO to parse a single response from API like this, ignoring unneeded properties:

For example, using Lombok `@Data` and Jackson `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations

```java
@Data
public class Root {
    private Data data;
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data {
    // metadata field is skipped
    private List<Edge> edges;
}
```

- The resulting `StringComposite` may be defined like this:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StringComposite {
    private List<Edges> edges;
}
```

- So, the input strings are parsed into a list/stream `Root` POJOs, which are merged then into a single `StringComposite` using `Stream::flatMap`:

```java
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

List<String> apiResponses = ...; // build list of API responses

List<Edge> mergedEdges = apiResponses
    .stream()
    .map(str -> try { 
            return om.readValue(str, Root.class); 
        } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException jex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(jex);
        }) // Stream<Root>
    .flatMap(root -> root.getEdges().stream()) // Stream<Edge>
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Edge>

StringComposite result = new StringComposite(mergedEdges);
```